# Creating a grid of cells in SFML

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml, cellular-automata

Using C++, I wanted to create my first C++ graphical programs by learning the SFML library through creating a Conway's Game of Life implementation. My general thought process is by first creating a simple grid of cells that have the following data just starting off: x, y, and a state (either dead or alive but is set to dead initially). However I am having difficulty understanding how to create this in SFML, coming from a Java background one can make this with relative ease using a gridlayout, however, I am not sure how to approach making a grid of cells with each cell having individual data. How would I go about creating a grid of cells with what I currently have? Here is what I have so far, bear in mind majority of the code is incomplete and additions, and subtractions to the code, will be made, however my first step is to just create a grid of cells in which if I click a cell, it should print a response in console (similar to event listeners in java):

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Include/Grid.h"

const int32_t windowWidth = 1000; // Cols
const int32_t windowHeight = 800; // Rows

int main() {

    //For testing purposes, when the program is run, the grid should pop up,
    //and I should be able to place black squares on a white box grid for today
    Grid gameOfLife(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    gameOfLife.run();
    return 0;
}
```

cell.h:

```
#ifndef CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_CELL_H
#define CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_CELL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

//Use enum to keep track of the state of each cell
//When grid is initialized, each cell will have a state of dead
//However when the user places the cells by clicking on the boxes,
//and clicks the "Run" button, then the program will start

class Cell {

public:
    enum State {
        ALIVE,
        DEAD
    };

private:
    std::int32_t xCell;
    std::int32_t yCell;
    State cellState;

public:
    sf::RectangleShape cell;

    [[nodiscard]] int getX() const;
    [[nodiscard]] int getY() const;

    State getState();

    void setPosition(int xPos, int yPos);

    Cell(int xPos, int yPos, Cell::State state);

};
#endif //CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_CELL_H
```

cell.cpp:

```
#include "Include/Cell.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

Cell::Cell(int xPos, int yPos, Cell::State state) {
    this->xCell = xPos;
    this->yCell = yPos;
    this->cellState = state;
    this->cell = sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(10,10));
    cell.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    cell.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
}

int Cell::getX() const {
    return xCell;
}

int Cell::getY() const {
    return yCell;
}

Cell::State Cell::getState() {
    return cellState;
}

void Cell::setPosition(int xPos, int yPos) {
    xCell = xPos;
    yCell = yPos;
}
```

grid.h:

```
#ifndef CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_GRID_H
#define CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_GRID_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Cell.h"

class Grid {

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> gridVector;
    int32_t height;
    int32_t width;
    bool isRunning;

public:
    void initGridVector();

    void setWidth(int width);
    void setHeight(int height);

    void placeCell();
    void deleteCell();

    void gridCopy();
    void update();

    void run();

    void display(int gWidth, int gHeight) const;

    Grid(int gridWidth, int gridHeight);

};


#endif //CELLULARAUTOMATA2D_GRID_H
```

grid.cpp:

```
#include "Include/Grid.h"
#include "Include/Cell.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

Grid::Grid(int gridWidth, int gridHeight) {
    this->height = gridHeight;
    this->width = gridWidth;
    this->isRunning = false;
}

void Grid::initGridVector() {
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        std::vector<Cell> cellVec;
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            cellVec.push_back(*new Cell(i,j,Cell::DEAD));
        }
        gridVector.push_back(cellVec);
    }
}

void Grid::display(int gWidth, int gHeight) const {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(gWidth,gHeight), "Cellular Automata");

    //Run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen() && isRunning)
    {
        //Check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //"close requested" event: closes the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }
        window.clear();

        for (const auto & i : gridVector){
            for (const auto & j : i){
                window.draw(j.cell);
            }
        }

        window.display();
    }
}

void Grid::setWidth(int gWidth) {
    this->width = gWidth;
}

void Grid::setHeight(int gHeight) {
    this->height = gHeight;
}

void Grid::gridCopy() {

}

void Grid::update() {

}

void Grid::deleteCell() {

}

void Grid::placeCell() {

}

void Grid::run() {
    std::cout << "Automata is running" << std::endl;
    isRunning = true;
    initGridVector();
    display(width, height);

}
```

The run function will basically handle all the grid functionality, (Creating the grid with initialized cells, handling event listeners such as clicking a "start" button and allowing for the user to place cells).

Comment: I'm not seeing a question in there. Is it buried in all that code or did you just feel like giving us a status update?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Reworded the original prompt so I am more clear, I am asking how can I create a grid of cells using the code I currently have?

Comment: Well I think you already have. You have a `Cell` class and a `Grid` class and they seem to be doing stuff you would expect. Are you asking how to *display* the grid?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure where exactly to do so, what I have in mind is creating shapes provided a 2D vector as I have created, so each cell within the vector has the following data of an x and y, this x and y will represent its index within the 2D vector. I tried this with a nested for loop within the first while loop of the display function, but when doing so it crashed.

Comment: OK well each cell does have an x and y coordinate like you said and you also have a texture or shape of some sort associated with it based on its state. Iterate through each row and column like you have, draw the appropriate texture, or shape and walla. Now if it continues to crash and stepping through it with a debugger doesn't indicate the problem that's the code you should be posting so we can help you solve the problem with the crash.

Comment: I updated cell.h, cell.cpp, and grid.cpp, rather than crashing I now have a black screen with a small white square in the top left of the window and its pretty slow (probably because I have a nested for loop within the while loop). But it dosent crash completely. Now the Cell class has a rectangle attribute so I can actually draw rectangles to the screen however it seems like its only drawing to one place only even though each cell has its own x and y value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your cell class. When updating position you also must update the `sf::RectangleShape cell;` position because it is what really is important in drawing into the window.

It seems to you that you only have a one rect top-left corner because in reality all of them are in the same spot since the deafult position is [0,0].
In order to fix this you need to change `setPosition` and if you don't call it anywhere after creating and before drawing, then you also must change the constructor.

```
void Cell::setPosition(int xPos, int yPos) {
    ...
    cell.setPosition(xCell,yCell);//xCell and yCell must also had been updated
}
```

Also I want to adress the comment:

*its pretty slow (probably because I have a nested for loop within the while loop).*

Yes, because you are calling many draw function in one frame (one while loop iteration), and in order to prevent that you could use sf::VertexArray. It enables you to create your own "drawing type" however, in your case you would be able to create something similar to [their tilemap example](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php#example-tile-map) but without texture.